# gradle set external classpath

Tags: java, gradle, classpath

I'd like to share the classpath created by gradle with an external application (VIM) by exporting the classpath to $CLASSPATH. I've tried doing this in the shell via calling gradle and setting the variable but there is a bunch of extra output that makes this cumbersome. I've also looked at shelling commands via the gradle script but this seems to create a new shell instance and therefore doesn't affect env variables of the current shell.

Does anyone have any experience accomplishing this? Thanks for the help!

I think an example would help to clarify:

```
task classpath {
    classpathcmd = "export CLASSPATH=" + sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath.asPath
    // Prints too much extra text
    println classpathcmd
    // Executes command in another shell instance so the variable is "lost"
    exec {
        executable = "sh"
        args = classpathcmd
    }
    // Stracktrace because of file not found exception
    exec {
        commandLine classpathcmd
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either write a task for this and call it (perhaps using `--quiet`), or use the Gradle tooling API (perhaps from a vim plugin).

Comment: --quiet still prints a lot of extra text that would need to be parsed by awk or grep. I have written a task but it doesn't seem there is anyway to send commands to the current shell. I tried the "commandLine" function but it requires a file target so sending the "export" command results in a file not found.

Comment: Not sure which `commandLine` function you are talking about. If sending to std out doesn't cut it, then send it to a file. Or write a vim plugin that uses the Gradle tooling API (but this will take more effort).

Comment: I think writing to a file would work. I'll accept this as the answer if there isn't a more elegant solution. As far as the tooling api, I could go this route but VIM only supports Cruby and Cpython out of box to bridge to the JVM might be a substantial task.

Comment: I don't think shelling out will get you anywhere, for the reason you mentioned. (FWIW, the task isn't declared correctly; its whole body would have to be wrapped with `doLast {}`. However this won't solve the problem at hand.)

Comment: Writing out to a file ended up being the solution. I used a vim script snippet that loaded a ".vimrc.local" in the directory which set the classpath for the javacomplete.vim plugin. I added this task as a vim snippet so I can put it into build scripts going forward. Thanks!